# Unparseable date - in java

Tags: java, json, datetime

I'm trying to convert timestamps to date, I got this exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1604328483716" 
 at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:395)
```

All the timestamps values that I have, having a format like this  `1604328483716`

Comment: Please don't use `Date` and `SimpleDateFomat`. They're obsolete and [troublesome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/507738). Use classes from the `java.time` package instead, as T.J. Crowder already mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formatter is set up to handle the format `"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"`. `"1604328483716"` isn't remotely in that format.

The value `"1604328483716"` looks like the string version of a milliseconds-since-The-Epoch value. If so, convert it to a `long` (`Long.parseLong`) and use `new Date(theLongValue)`, which will give you a `Date` instance for Monday November 2nd 2020 14:48:03 GMT (or whatever that is in your local timezone).

You might also consider using the newer date/time API in the `java.time` package, rather than `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 0):

1604328483716

It is timestamp: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/?ref=dtf.ru

So, simply do:

```
long modificationTime = rec.getJsonNumber("modificationTime").lngValue();
Date date = new Date(modificationTime);
```